# .NET version in IIS with COM libraries in BIN

Tags: com, asp-classic, iis-7.5

I have a client with a classic ASP website which runs `Server.CreateObject()` to access .NET libraries stored in the bin directory. (It's an ugly hack, I know...) Their setup guidelines say to set up the site in IIS as a .NET 2.0 site. But I'm wondering whether this requirement means the dlls also have to be compiled with a 2.0 target version to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all i do not think this is an "ugly hack". in my opinion it is quite a good thing to have the possibility to use .net in legacy classic asp applications.

the next thing is it is irrelevant where those .net dlls exist when they are only used by classic asp because they have to be "registered" by regasm.exe.

the .net dlls have to be compiled with a 2.0 or 3.5 target version when the application pool uses the 2.0 .net framework.

when compiled with 4.0 target version the application pool must be set to 4.0 also.

Comment: What if it's an MVC library using Razor that's accessed via COM, with Response.Write() outputting HTML strings in classic ASP? I hope I get your vote for "ugly" now...